# How to capture status code in catch block of an azure function written .net core 3.1 using visual studio 2019

Tags: c#, exception, azure-functions, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm developing azure functions written in .NET CORE 3.1 using Visual Studio 2019. I have a catch block as below

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    log.LogError(ex, "Error: " + ex.Message + "");
    var errormodel = new { isError = true, Message = ex.Message, errorInnerException = ex.InnerException, stackTrace = ex.StackTrace };
    return new ObjectResult(errormodel)
    {

    };
    throw ex;
}
```

I'm not able to capture status code here... Any idea how to capture status code in catch block?

Comment: which kind of triggers are you using? http trigger or others?

Comment: http triggers only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install this package: [ServiceStack 5.10.4](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack/), then in your catch block, you can just use the `ToStatusCode()` method.

The code like below:

```
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            var x = ex.ToStatusCode();
            log.LogError(ex, "Error: " + ex.Message + ", Status Code:" + ex.ToStatusCode());
            
            var errormodel = new { isError = true, Message = ex.Message, errorInnerException = ex.InnerException, stackTrace = ex.StackTrace, StatusCode = ex.ToStatusCode() };
            return new ObjectResult(errormodel)
            {

            };
            throw ex;
        }
```